# Display Dates that have 0 count data

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a query like this

```
SELECT
  d.create_at :: DATE AS dates,
  count(r.id) AS usages
FROM reports r LEFT JOIN dispatches d ON r.dispatch_id = d.id
  LEFT JOIN messages m ON d.message_id = m.id
WHERE r.status = 'SUCCESS' AND r.update_at :: DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-10' AND m.client_id = 6
GROUP BY dates
ORDER BY dates;
```

that will generate result like this

[image: result]

there's no data on date 2020-05-03 and 2020-05-08 so they wont showed on result

How do I add those dates that have no data and give the count data 0 as value?

Sorry for I'm new to Postgres and DB in general

I've followed several solution from everywhere doesn't seem to get the result I want yet

I try to use generate_series but no result came out

```
SELECT
  x.day AS dates,
  count(r.id) AS usages
FROM (
   SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2020-05-01'
                        , timestamp '2020-05-10'
                        , interval '1 day')::date
   ) x(day)
    left join dispatches d on d.create_at = x.day
    LEFT JOIN reports r ON d.id = r.dispatch_id
    LEFT JOIN messages m ON d.message_id = m.id
WHERE r.status = 'SUCCESS' AND r.update_at :: DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-10' AND m.client_id = 6
GROUP BY dates
ORDER BY dates;
```

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You were close, but your WHERE clause turns the outer join back into an inner join. You need to move that condition into the JOIN condition.

```
SELECT x.day AS dates,
       count(r.id) AS usages
FROM (
   SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2020-05-01'
                        , timestamp '2020-05-10'
                        , interval '1 day')::date
) x(day)
  left join dispatches d on d.create_at = x.day
  LEFT JOIN reports r 
         ON d.id = r.dispatch_id
        and r.status = 'SUCCESS' 
        AND r.update_at::DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-10' 
        AND m.client_id = 6
    LEFT JOIN messages m ON d.message_id = m.id
GROUP BY dates
ORDER BY dates;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. All the dates showed but the usages or count data all return 0

Comment: Move the condition `m.client_id = 6` to the `LEFT JOIN ... m` clause...

Comment: Thank you @UsagiMiyamoto I already move that before and the result all usages or count is 0

Comment: @IntanKirana If the count is always zero, then the join condition to the `reports` table do not select any row from that table. Try to remove the conditions one after the other and see which one causes that. Then check your data to see why it's missing

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name already remove one by one until no condition but still return 0

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT
  dt.date_seq :: DATE AS dates,
  count(r.id) AS usages
FROM reports r LEFT JOIN dispatches d ON r.dispatch_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN messages m ON d.message_id = m.id
FULL OUTER JOIN (select CURRENT_DATE + i as date_seq from generate_series(date '2020- 
05-01'- CURRENT_DATE, date '2020-05-10' - CURRENT_DATE ) i)
dt
ON d.create_at = dt.date_seq
WHERE r.status = 'SUCCESS' AND r.update_at :: DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-05-01' AND 
'2020-05-10' AND m.client_id = 6
GROUP BY dates
ORDER BY dates;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping but the output still doesnt right